# Attempting to download GraphViz on Anaconda on windows

Tags: windows, anaconda, graphviz

I have attempted to install GraphViz on Anaconda but this is the message that I keep on getting.

GraphViz's executables not found

Comment: Can you add the commands you used to install `GraphViz` and all steps required to obtain the error message you posted?

Comment: what did you type to install GraphViz.

Answer (score 0):

You can install graphviz for anaconda by following these steps:

1. Open anaconda navigator
2. go to environments
3. select not installed
4. and then search for graphviz

[image]

5. select the required package and click apply
   [image]
6. the following dialogue box will appear.... click apply and it will start downloading
   [image]

Comment: Also, please be more specific about your problems. because right now your question is not clear, so provide more information.